# .net core xunit How verify if method was called from inherited class

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, xunit

I have a base class called BaseService, and i want to verify if method IsValid was called in my unit test.

```
public interface IBaseService
{
    bool IsValid<Dto, DtoValidator>(Dto entityDto, DtoValidator validator) where DtoValidator : AbstractValidator<Dto>;
}

public class BaseService : IBaseService
{
    protected readonly IMapper _mapper;
    protected readonly INotificationService _notification;

    public BaseService(
        IMapper mapper,
        INotificationService notification)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _notification = notification;
    }

    public virtual bool IsValid<Dto, DtoValidator>(Dto entityDto, DtoValidator validator) where DtoValidator : AbstractValidator<Dto>
    {
        var result = validator.Validate(entityDto);
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            _notification.Notify(error.ErrorMessage);
        }
        return result.IsValid;
    }
}
```

Class that use BaseService , some parts of code was omited

```
public interface IAfiliadoService : IBaseService {}

public class AfiliadoService : BaseService, IAfiliadoService
{
    public AfiliadoService(
        IMapper mapper,
        INotificationService notification) : base(mapper, notification)
    {
        _afiliadoRepository = afiliadoRepository;
        _lojaRepository = lojaRepository;          
    }

    public async Task<AfiliadoResponseDto> AddAsync(AddAfiliadoRequestDto request)
    {
        if (IsValid(request, new AddAfiliadoRequestDtoValidator()))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

In my test project i created those classes

```
public class MockBaseService
{
    public readonly Mock<IMapper> _mapper;
    public readonly Mock<INotificationService> _notification;

    public MockBaseService()
    {
        _mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
        _notification = new Mock<INotificationService>();
    }
}


public class AfiliadoServiceTest : MockBaseService
{       
    private readonly IAfiliadoService _afiliadoService;

    public AfiliadoServiceTest()
    {
        _afiliadoService = new AfiliadoService(
            _mapper.Object,
            _notification.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task AdicionarUsuarioComEmailQueJaExisteDeveNotificar()
    {
        var request = new AddAfiliadoRequestDto();

        var result = await _afiliadoService.AddAsync(request);

        Assert.Null(result);

        _notification
            .Verify(v => v.Notify(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);

        // Here i want verify if method IsValid was called Once, like the verification above
    }
}
```

I tried some things but with no success.
Exemple with what i want.

```
var mock = new Mock<AfiliadoService>();
mock.Verify(v => v.IsValid(request, new AddAfiliadoRequestDtoValidator()), Times.Once);


var mock = new Mock<AfiliadoService>(_mapper.Object,
            _notification.Object);
        var result = await mock.Object.AddAsync(request);
        mock.Verify(v => v.IsValid(request, new AddAfiliadoRequestDtoValidator()), Times.Once);
```

This last one i got the message

```
Message: 
Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: v => v.IsValid<AddAfiliadoRequestDto, AddAfiliadoRequestDtoValidator>(AddAfiliadoRequestDto, AddAfiliadoRequestDtoValidator)

Performed invocations:

   Mock<AfiliadoService:1> (v):

      BaseService.IsValid<AddAfiliadoRequestDto, AddAfiliadoRequestDtoValidator>(AddAfiliadoRequestDto, AddAfiliadoRequestDtoValidator)
```

What im doing wrong?

Im using .net core - 3.1
xunit - 2.4.1
Moq - 4.16.0

Comment: You may look at [`CallBase` property](https://github.com/moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#customizing-mock-behavior)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski i tried this too, i get the same Message showed above. I also tried `mock.As<IBaseService>().Verify(v => v.IsValid(request, new AddAfiliadoRequestDtoValidator()), Times.Once);`